# Multiple ListItem Owner

Tags: 2010, list, development, visual-studio, content-type

I need to create a List that contains multiple listitems. Each listitem should have 2 autors, or 2 persons wich have permissions to change the item. The users who are allowed to change the items are definied in two fields of the ListItem (Administrator and Locum).

Is there a possibility to bind this fields (perhabs as Autor)? 
Or does any one have an other idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage individual ListItem permissions in SharePoint 2010.

What you will want to do is add an event receiver to the ItemAdded event of the ListItem. In that event receiver, you can break the inheritance of the ListItem and attach custom permissions to it.

Here are some links which will help you create a item receiver for the ItemAdded event:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx

http://sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/sharepoint-event-handlers-getting-item-properties-in-the-itemadded-event/

And here is how to set custom permissions on a ListItem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/f2ccd61a-8828-4c17-8360-20d45d6b9514

http://www.mylifeinaminute.com/2008/03/27/sharepoint-list-permissions/